# Is this question about an algorithm ontopic on cs.SE?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

Is this the right forum to ask the question I posted on 
http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Here is a link to the question.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/291978/finding-meeting-point-of-slow-and-fast-pointers-in-linked-list-loop

I am not sure how to move the question here, if Moderators can help please.

Comment: To be honest, I can't really tell what your question on Programmers is asking. But, if you can clarify what the question is, it does look like it would be more on-topic here than there. It seems to be an algorithm analysis question, rather than a question about how to be a programmer. To ask for a qeustion to be moved, click the "flag" link below the question on Programmers and ask the mods to move it.

Comment: Technical answer: if you want your question migrated, flag it for the moderators on [programmers.SE]. Thanks for asking us first, though!